# SOLVED CiviMobile won't login "please install CiviMobile in your CiviCRM"

Tags: civimobile

When I try to use CiviMobile on my phone to login to CiviCRM I get error "Please install CiviMobile extension in your CiviCRM".

- Drupal7.67 / CiviCRM 5.12.2 / php7.2 / Running on Aegir
- Installed CiviMobile 4.0.1 on my Android phone from Play Store and
  can successfully log in to the demo.
- installed CiviMobileAPI v4.0.2 from the repository and it reflects
  as installed.
- Installation directory is    /data/disk/xxx/static/platforms/platform_name/sites/collaborate2019.co.za/files/civicrm/ext/com.agiliway.civimobileapi
- CiviCRM/Administer/CiviMobile settings reflects that the extension is
  up to date
- Login username and password and website URL
  https://collaborate2019.co.za are correct (when I tried
  https://collaborate2019.co.za/civicrm it gave me "Server API error")

Any ideas what I can try?

Comment: is there any way you could check the civi logs or your server logs to see if it's connecting or experiencing an error and then narrow it down from there? can you replicate this from a fresh install? I used to have a site hosted Aegir (barracuda aegir), it did some funky stuff, could you pull it off that platform and test it out to see if its config could be compounding an issue?

Comment: Hi @Zachary. There is no info in the Drupal dblog or the CiviCRM log, and my hosting provider says they can't find anything in the system logs. They did suggest that I move the extension from /sites/collaborate2019.co.za/files/civicrm/ext/ to the code space. Can you recall where you placed the CiviCRM extensions when you hosted on Aegir?

Comment: It's been forever, sorry I can't remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Civimobile team was great. After updating the extension and app to the latest version 4.1.1 the app works like a dream.

Answer (score 0):

our discussion is here https://github.com/agiliway/com.agiliway.civimobileapi/issues/30

Let's continue in github.

Comment: Thanks for your post but this doesn't really answer the question. Are you able to provide the full answer here rather than linking to another site?